# How to specify a Class of specific generics type?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I know following codes works.

```java
Object get(final String name);

<T> T get(final String name, final Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(get(name));
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

```java
get(name, Supplier<ByteBuffer>.class); // compiler doesn't like this.
```

I currently casting the raw result like this.

```java
(Supplier<ByteBuffer>) get(name);
(Supplier<ByteBuffer>) get(name, Supplier.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

if your casts are reliable, you can do this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> T getWithCast(final String name) {
    return (T) get(name);
}
```